# Looking for Node.js memory library

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for an advanced node.js library that would allow me to read memory of process and search for certain information in it (mostly finding strings, kind of like cheat-engine or crysearch).

I already tried:

https://github.com/Rob--/memoryjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winprocess

Neither of them suited my needs (bad docs, hard to use, not enough functionality).

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic on SO, particularly because such questions don't encourage good answers. *not enough functionality* - only you know what functionality you need, so you need to check them all and possibly fork one of them if none suits your needs. Possibly makes sense to use it Node as a wrapper for some third-party binary.

Comment: Well, I searched through some libraries and just couldn't find good one. That's why I'm asking for help, You're right that only I know what functionality I need, but when my research isn't good enough I ask for help - so that people can post their suggestions of libraries for me to check.

Tried going with binaries as well, but wrapping it became too heavy-time-consuming task.